# ImportError: cannot import name 'Annotated' and 'ValueRange'

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic, python-dataclasses

Hello I am using Python 3.8

And I am implementing a dataclass with a fix list in order to do this I have the following code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Annotated, List, ValueRange
from pydantic import validate_arguments

@validate_arguments
@dataclass
class WorldArea:
    ...
    data: Annotated[List[float], ValueRange(1, 3)]
    ...
```

The idea is that data will be a list with 1, 2 or 3 elements, as you can see I am using Annotated and ValueRange, but when I execute I get the following error:

> File "a.py", line 2, in 
> from typing import  List, ValueRange ImportError: cannot import name 'Annotated' from 'typing'
>
> File "a.py", line 2, in 
> from typing import  List, ValueRange ImportError: cannot import name 'ValueRange' from 'typing'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) has been introduced in Python 3.9 (see last line in the linked section).

`ValueRange` (and `MaxLen`) in the linked section appear to be example classes.

They are *not* part of the `typing` package.

Comment: I change pyenv to use 3.9-dev and confirm the issue is gone

Comment: Thank you, it also fixed it for me when trying to use pybind11-stubgen. With 3.9 it works great.